# In a group $G$ if $x^3=e$ has more than one solution then the number of it's solutions is odd.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

In a finite group $G,$ if the equation $x^3=e$ where $e$ is the identity has more than one solution, then the number of it's solutions is odd.

My attempt
Suppose we have even number of distinct solutions to this equation.Also since $e^3=e,e$ is also a solution. Therefore there are odd number of solutions to this equation which are distinct from $e$. Also since $a^3a^{-3}=e \implies {(a^{-1})}^3=e$ and hence $a^{-1}$ is also a solution. Let the set $S$ denote the solutions which does not contain $e$. Clearly $|S|$ is of the form $2n-1.$ But for each $a\in S,a^{-1}\in S.$ Since $S$ is finite and has odd number of elements there exists $b\in S$ such that $b^{-1}=b$. Then $b^3=b^2b=b,$ a contradiction.

Comment: By the way, the number of solution is also odd if it does not have more than one solution

Comment: I would rather not use contradiction. Suppose $a$ is a solution $\ne e$.  Then $a^{-1}$ is a solution, and $a^{-1}\ne a$. So the solutions $\ne e$ can be divided into mutually inverse pairs, and therefore there is an even number of them.

Comment: Why do I have a downvote? would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I do not know why you have a downvote. Your proof is fundamentally correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Fact:** If $x^3=e$ has more than one solution *(including x=e)*, then the number of solutions is odd.

**Proof:**

Suppose that $x\neq e$ is a solution to $x^3=e$.  Then we note that it is impossible to have $x=x^{-1}$, since that would mean that $x^2=x^3=e$, which would mean that $x=e$.

So, $x\neq x^{-1}$. However, as you rightly noted, $x^{-1}$ solves the same equation, since $x^{-3}=e$.

So, all solutions come in pairs that include a solution and its distinct inverse. So, since the non-identity solutions come in pairs, there must be an even number of such solutions. So, the overall number of solutions must be odd.

Comment: I would change that last paragraph to "So all *non-identity* solutions come in pairs..."

Comment: I completely understand your solution,it is elegant! thanks,.. but I still don't get why my proof is wrong...because $a,a^{-1}$ both belong to $S$ and $S$ contains odd number of elements, there exists one element whose inverse has to be itself which would be a contradiction, right?

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your proof. It was fine, I hadn't noticed you were proving by contradiction.